# elm-css: How to give a value to `opacity`

Tags: elm

I am playing around with `elm-css`.
Most of the things work as I expect them.
But I am not able to give a correct value to the `Css.opacity` function.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Css.opacity 0.5
```

which gives the error:

```
Function `opacity` is expecting the argument to be:

    Css.Number compatible

But it is:

    Float
```

The `Css.Number` is a type alias in the following form:

```
type alias Number compatible =
     { compatible | value : String, number : Compatible }
```

But I don't understand how to create a valid value for the `Css.opacity` function...

Answer (score 10):

You can create input for `opacity` by using one of the "unitless" functions, like `Css.int` or `Css.num`. For example:

```
-- 42% opaque
translucent = Css.opacity (Css.num 0.42)
```

It is "unitless" because the CSS property of opacity [does not define a unit like `px` or percent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).